# Creating a source to destination map view for windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8

I have a default geocoordinate. Another geocoorinate which the user will provide. I want to change the change the map view such such that the source and destination can be clearly seen on the phone window with max zoom possible. Please help on how to approach this problem. I tried using setview() but i coudn't find an overload which could do the task.

```
public async void ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(string mapvariable)
   {
       JObject o = JObject.Parse(mapvariable);
       string successcallback = o["successCallback"].ToString();
       string failutecallback = o["failureCallback"].ToString();
       var markerifo = o["markerInfo"];
       int count = markerifo.Count();
       try
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               drawmap(markerifo[i],"red");
           }

           Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
           Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

           JObject current = new JObject();
           current["locationLatitude"] = myGeoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
           current["locationLongitude"] = myGeoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
           current["locationDescription"] = "Your Current Location";
           current["locationName"] = "";
           drawmap(current,"blue");

           GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(myGeoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, myGeoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);



           MapAppzillon.SetView(myGeoCoordinate1,6);

         gobject.ContentPanel.Children.Add(MapAppzillon);

           var jsonstring = "{\"successMessage\":\" Map Displayed \"}";
           string[] param = { successcallback, jsonstring };
          gobject.invokeScript("StringToJsonObject", param);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           var jsonstring = "{\"errorCode\":\"APZ-CNT-107\"}";
           string[] param = { failutecallback, jsonstring };
           gobject.invokeScript("StringToJsonObject", param);
       }
   }

public void drawmap(JToken markerifo,string color)
   {
       double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(markerifo["locationLatitude"].ToString());
       double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(markerifo["locationLongitude"].ToString());
       myGeoCoordinate1 = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);

       Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
       if (color == "red")
       {
           myCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
       }
       else
           myCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
       myCircle.Height = 20;
       myCircle.Width = 20;
       myCircle.Opacity = 50;
       myCircle.Tap += (sender, e) => myCircle_Tap(sender, markerifo["locationDescription"].ToString(), markerifo["locationName"].ToString());
       // myCircle.Tap +=    myCircle_Tap;
       MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
       myLocationOverlay.Content = myCircle;


       myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0.5, 0.5);
       myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate1;

       MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
       myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);
       MapAppzillon.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);

   }
```

Edit: I tried using dispatcher.Invoke and it finally worked. but now its loading only once . when i press the back button and specify another geocoordinate setview dosent work. Is there any solution to this.

```
     List<GeoCoordinate> the2Points = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
       the2Points.Add(myGeoCoordinate1);
       the2Points.Add(myGeoCoordinate);
       rect = LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(the2Points);




     gobject.ContentPanel.Children.Add(MapAppzillon);
     MapAppzillon.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
         MapAppzillon.SetView(rect);
     });
     await Task.Delay(150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use the SetView method on the Map control. But it needs a BoundingRectangle to work!

So a quick code snippet:

```
List<GeoCoordinate> the2Points = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
the2Points.Add(point1);
the2Points.Add(point2);
LocationRectangle rect = LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(the2Points);
TheMapControl.SetView(rect);
```

Comment: Dosent work. Its not being zoomed. Maybe you have to specify the thickness with bounding rectangle?

Comment: I'm using it in an app that is in the store, it's zooming. But you don't have any 'say' over the zooming rendering time.

Comment: When you mentioned mapcontrol do you mean a Mapcore object. Im using a map object, setting the view and then adding it to content panel

Comment: In your code I see MapAppzillon, I suppose that is your map control on your view...